# Trying to delay JQuery hover function

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation bar with different list elements, and I'm trying to call up different background images for each one whenever a user hovers over the element. I've gotten it to work, but when I try to change the code so the images fade in and out, I'm running into roadblocks.

Here's the Javascript I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").hover(
        function () {
            var navid = $(this).attr('id'); 
            $(this).addClass(navid);  
        },
        function () {
            var navid = $(this).attr('id'); 
            $(this).removeClass(navid);  }
    );
});
```

I've tried setTimeout and transitions without any luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What roadblocks do you have?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ Have you tried fadein?

Comment: Please post the code that doesn't work, not the one that does work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to fade the images to transparent on hover and back to opaque on mouseleave. You would use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").hover(
        function () {
            var navid = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).addClass(navid);
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0);
        },
        function () {
            var navid = $(this).attr('id'); 
            $(this).removeClass(navid);
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
        }
    );
});
```